# Lock wait timeout is not happening in INSERT query mysql

Tags: mysql, timeout, locking, mysql-5.7

I am using Mysql 5.7.18 with innodb storage engine.
Innodb lock wait timeout is 5 min.
Isolation level READ_COMMITED

In some cases(Will explain the case) INSERT queries is waiting for lock more than 5 min and doesn't throw lock wait time out exception.

Table Design:

```
mysql> show create table Users;
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                    |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Users | CREATE TABLE `Users` (
  `ID` bigint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NAME` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table Purchases;
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table     | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Purchases | CREATE TABLE `Purchases` (
  `PURCHASEID` bigint(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NAME` text NOT NULL,
  `PURCHASEDBYID` bigint(19) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PURCHASEID`),
  KEY `Purchases_FK4_IDX` (`PURCHASEDBYID`),
  CONSTRAINT `Purchases_FK4` FOREIGN KEY (`PURCHASEDBYID`) REFERENCES `Users` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Records in table:

```
mysql> select * from Users;
+----+------+
| ID | NAME |
+----+------+
|  1 | Jhon |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from Purchases;
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| PURCHASEID | NAME      | PURCHASEDBYID |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
|          1 | purchase1 |             1 |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Case in which lock wait timeout is not occured.

In Transaction 1:

```
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> update Users set name="Max" where ID=1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Transaction 1 not committed or rollbacked.

In Transaction 2:

```
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into Purchases values (2,"purchase2",1);
```

Transaction 2 is waiting S lock on Users table row .
But Transaction 1 is already holding X lock on the same row.

In this case i expect Transaction 2 will get lock wait time out after 5 min.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST where INFO IS NOT NULL;
+---------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID      | USER | HOST      | DB   | COMMAND | TIME | STATE     | INFO                                                                |
+---------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 8545284 | root | localhost | test | Query   |    0 | executing | SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST where INFO IS NOT NULL |
| 8541675 | root | localhost | test | Query   |  308 | update    | insert into Purchases values (2,"purchase2",1)                      |
+---------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But it didn't happens. It is running more than 5 min.
What is reason behind it ? Please help any one.

Comment: Can you show the value of `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`?. `SELECT @@GLOBAL.innodb_lock_wait_timeout, @@SESSION.innodb_lock_wait_timeout;`. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: +-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.innodb_lock_wait_timeout | @@SESSION.innodb_lock_wait_timeout |
+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|                               300 |                                300 |
+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+

Comment: It looks like a bug in 5.7.18. In 5.7.26 I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes it is a bug in 5.7.18. Can't to find which bug caused this. Share me if you find the bug id regarding this bug @wchiquito